# Seed multiple tables from one backend/builder form?

Tags: php, laravel, octobercms

I'm trying to insert data into multiple related tables from one (builder) back end form/model - but it seems I'm doing something wrong.

t1 posts (used for model Posts.php)

```
id, flag1, flag2 , created_at, updated_at
```

t2 post_content (used for model Posts_content.php)

```
id, content
```

I've tried expanding the model (Posts.php) used for the form as explained in the relations documentation of octobercms like so:

```
public $hasOne = ['content' => ['Test\Gcn\Models\Post_content', 'key' => 'id', 'otherKey' => 'id']];
```

While this does not produce an error when a record is created via the backend controller, no data is actually written to posts_content.

I've also tried to solve it with a proxy field

fields.yaml (of model Posts.php)

```
post_content[content]:
label: 'Post here'
size: ''
mode: tab
span: full
type: markdown
```

Posts.php (with the proxy field)

```
public function formExtendModel($model)
{
    /*
     * Init proxy field model if we are creating the model
     */
    if ($this->action == 'create') {
        $model->post_content = new Post_content;
    }
    return $model;
}
```

According to the error message, the array needs to be set to be jsonable. But even after that it looks like it's trying to insert the data in the wrong table.

What is the proper way to achieve this?
I'm trying to have one form where a user can enter some flags (checkboxes and the like) and a text field which should be inserted into post_content table with the correct id.

I appreciate your time and help, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

From my opinion, you have to do many changes in your structure like below:

1) Add content_id in your `posts` table

```
id, flag1, flag2, content_id, created_at, updated_at
```

And second table should be **`contents`** table

```
id, content
```

**content_id** will be used to create **one to one** relationship between **Post** and **Content**. For more information about relations [click here](https://octobercms.com/docs/database/relations#introduction).

2) Then, you have to define models `Post` for posts and `Content` for all contents.

In Content model give **`One to one`** relationship.

```
public $hasOne = [
        'post' => 'Test\Gcn\Models\Post'
    ];
```

If you give this type of relation, this will find **`content_id`** in your Post model so it set direct relationship between **Post** and **Content**.

3) Your form field should be like

In **Post** model `fields.yaml` should be

```
fields:
    flag1:
        label: 'Flag 1'
        oc.commentPosition: ''
        span: left
        type: text
    flag2:
        label: 'Flag 2'
        oc.commentPosition: ''
        span: auto
        type: text
```

And In **Content** model `fields.yaml` should be

```
fields:
    post:
        label: Post
        oc.commentPosition: ''
        nameFrom: flag1
        descriptionFrom: description
        span: auto
        type: relation
    content:
        label: Content
        size: small
        oc.commentPosition: ''
        span: left
        type: textarea
```

and `columns.yaml` should be

```
columns:
    content:
        label: Content
        type: text
        searchable: true
        sortable: true
    post:
        label: Post
        select: flag1
        relation: post
        searchable: true
        sortable: true
```

For more details about the backend, you can go here...1) [form relation](https://octobercms.com/docs/backend/forms#widget-relation) 2) [column relation](https://octobercms.com/docs/backend/lists#column-relation).

This all is from my side. Now analyze all this and try your code. And tell me if you have any query.

Thank you.

Comment: Hello,

First of all thank you for your reply.
Unfortunately your code does not work either, I did a fresh install and setup the the two tables, models and .yaml file exactly as you said.

Just to make sure, in this the controller would be created for Content right?

Comment: Yes, you have to add controllers too. It seems you are new to octobercms. Use this plugin to develop your backend [Rainlab Builder](https://octobercms.com/plugin/rainlab-builder). And you should read octobercms docs in brief.

Comment: @guy23234 Generally, Three parts are required in the framework. 1) Models 2) Views 3) Controllers. In your fresh OctoberCMS project you haven't defined controllers yet. So this is not working.